# Input search field in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search field that I use to search some data on my Mysql DB

here is the code:

```
 $query=$_POST['query'] <//----this is only field input I use to search---->

 $sql="SELECT condizione, id, nome FROM clienti WHERE nome LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR 
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
 echo  "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for " .$query. "</p>";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $nome=$row['nome'];
 $condizione=$row['condizione'];
 $id=$row['id'];


  if($condizione=="aperta") {
  echo "<form method='post' action=''><p><h3>".$nome."</h3>Scheda N&deg; ".$id.".
  "blablablablablablabalbala"."<br/><br/><input type='submit' name='close'   value='CLOSE' /></form>";


  $today=date("d-m-Y");

  if(isset($_POST['close']))    {

  $sql="UPDATE my_table Set condizione='chiusa' where nome='$nome'";
  $rssql = mysql_query($sql);
  echo "done!!";
  }
  }
```

So, if a do a research it appears the record I'd like to search, in a form, with teh button CLOSE. If I click on it it change the field condizione in "chiusa" in all records not in the only record i searched.

Comment: 1) Use "mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query'])" -> security. 2) Try to by ecplicit with datatypes. Change "if($condizione=="aperta")" to "if($condizione === "aperta")". 3) Use DateTime $today= new DateTime("now");, btw. $today is never used?.

Comment: your `$sql` is incomplete

Comment: what it means is incomplete?